# Writting to a txt file inside dropbox with processing.js/javascript

Tags: javascript, text, processing, dropbox, processing.js

I'm creating an application using processing.js and hosting the result via dropbox public folder, the idea is to use a .txt file generated via that platform to comunicate certain data to a local 3d modelling enviroment (rhinoceros/grasshopper), is it possible to write to a .txt file hosted in the public folder in dropbox directly from the sketch running in the web? 
I mean, using: saveStrings("test.txt","this is an example");
the html containing the sketch, the .txt file and the sketch file itself are all stored in the same public folder in dropbox, you can see the site here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97841548/kinetica%20App/KineticaAppHTML.html

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly access your local filesystem from a web page like that, and you don't get write access to your Dropbox account just by virtue of the KineticaAppHTML.html page being hosted on Dropbox.

One way to do this however would be to use the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers). You could either proxy the file writes to a server you control and then have that server make the API calls to Dropbox, or you could use the Dropbox API directly from JavaScript on your KineticaAppHTML.html page.

Dropbox offers a JavaScript SDK you can use:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/sdks/js

There's a tutorial here, though it focuses on datastores functionality and not files:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/tutorial/js

The basics for authenticating the user are relevant though.

Once authenticated, you can use this method to write new contents to the file in your Dropbox:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/datastore/docs/js#Dropbox.Client.writeFile

Note however that this strategy only results in you yourself, i.e., in your own browser, being able to make Dropbox API calls. If you want other users to use this to, this setup would have them connecting to their own Dropbox accounts. If you need them to connect to only your own account, you'd need to host and use your own actual web app, like I mentioned earlier, where you could safely make API calls to your own account. (You could technically avoid this by embedding an access token in your web page, but this is highly discouraged due the security implications there.)

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: no.

Webpages in your browser do not have read/write access to your file system. Only the web.

Long answer: yes, but not the way you describe.

If you have a server running with a RESTful API that you can call by URL (like any other API on the web), then you can use any "ajax" approach there is to communicate with that, giving it the data it needs to generate those files, and making it responsible for putting them in the right dropbox folder.